# Send Auto Email with duplicate Word/ID

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Below are my code to send auto email, but this sends each ID with 1 email.
What I want is to compile duplicate id first before send the auto email.
As an example below which service tag are duplicate ID. Apologies, can't put all codes here because I'm getting an error.

[image]

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("W" & i) = "YES" And _
    OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("B" & i) = "Ruz" And _
    OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("Y" & i) = "" Then

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rngTilte = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngTilte = OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("D1:X1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("D" & i & ":" & "X" & i). _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetFolderFromID(EntryID, StoreID)
    Set myTasks = Fldr.items

    For Each olMail In myTasks

    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, Cells(i, 4), vbTextCompare) > 0) And _
    (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, Cells(i, 6), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
```

with function below

```
    Function RangetoHTML(rngTilte As Range, rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim NR As Long  ' Next Aavailable Row

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    ' Amended to paste two ranges
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        rngTilte.Copy
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        ' Add second range
        NR = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        rng.Copy
        .Cells(NR, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(NR, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(NR, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        ' End of add second range
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Edit 1

I try with this and it work.

```
Dim Criteria As Range
Set Criteria = OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Cells(i, 4)
OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Columns("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Criteria.Value
OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Columns("Z:Z").AutoFilter _
Field:=26, Criteria1:=""

Set rng = Nothing
Set rngTilte = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rngTilte = OOW.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("D1:X" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
```

And now i facing another problem.
How can i move to next ID if after filter current ID and i find support column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this - I assume that you want to send 1 email for each Service ID, but listing all of the parts (in this case, 3)

The simplest method is to sort the list by Service ID, then store the Service ID you are working on, and check rows until the Service ID changes.  Then, that gives you all of the rows/parts that need to be included in that email.

If you don't want to sort the list, then you can store "done" Service IDs (in a Dictionary or deliminated string ("|A|B|" means "C" has not been done, as "|C|" is not found by`InStr`)) and either Filter for each new Service ID then use `.SpecialCells` to looks at the rows that are shown, or (inefficient) loop through until the end of the table and add any data from rows with the same service ID

Comment: thank you for your help and trying with filter method.
Can you help how to move next ID if current ID in support column is empty